# Whats wrong with this my timer?

Tags: java, netbeans, timer

Ok so i am halfway done with this timer script but i noticed when it runs the functions the second time it does not take in inputs anymore any idea why?
It does take in all and waits for inputs on start

```
public class ManagingLifts {


    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        Timer timer = new Timer();

        DeliveryMan d = new DeliveryMan();
        Hacker h = new Hacker();
        Lift id = new Lift();
        ArrayList<Person> p = new ArrayList();
        ArrayList<String> who = new ArrayList();



        int MINUTES = 2; // setting the duration of timer for people entering lift



        timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() // task to be run every 2 minute
        {
    @Override
    public void run()
    {
        int counter = 0;
        int HorD = (int)(Math.random() * 2) + 1; // decides who gets into the lift
        if (HorD <= 1)  // 
        {
            System.out.println("What is your name?");
            String name = sc.nextLine();

            System.out.println("What is your NRIC?");
            String nric = sc.nextLine();

            System.out.println("What is your Country?");
            String country = sc.nextLine();

            System.out.println("What floor do you wan to go?");
            int floor = sc.nextInt();

            if(floor >=50)  //making sure they only go to allowed floors
            {
                System.out.println("You can only access floors 40 - 50!");

            }

           Person list = new Person(name, nric);
           p.add(list);
           h.setCountry(country); 
           who.add("Hacker"); // to have a list of who entered the lift
           counter = +2;

        }

        else if (HorD >= 2)
        {

             System.out.println("What is your name?");
            String name2 = sc.nextLine();

            System.out.println("What is your NRIC?");
            String nric2 = sc.nextLine();

            System.out.println("What type of food are you delivering?");
            String food = sc.nextLine();

            System.out.println("What floor do you want to go?");
            int floor2 = sc.nextInt();

            if(floor2 >=31)
            {
                System.out.println("You can only access floors 2 - 30!");

            }

            Person list2 = new Person(name2, nric2);
            p.add(list2);
            d.setTypeofF(food);
            who.add("DeliveryGuy"); // who entered the lift

            counter = +2;
        }
           if(counter > 200) // stop running lift after 200min
        {
            timer.cancel();
        }


    }


        }, 0, 1000 * 60 * MINUTES); // will run this function every 2min




    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When reading the floor number, you're reading only the next int, but not the `enter` to move to the next line.  Since this is not read, the next time the loop starts, the `name` will be an empty string.

So add a `sc.nextLine()` when reading the floor, or just read a String and convert it to an int yourself using `Integer.parseInt`.

Alternatively, you can also discard all the input from `System.in` in between loops, by just recreating the `Scanner`.  Instead of creating the Scanner outside the task, just create the Scanner as the first thing when your task runs (so inside the `run` method).

Comment: Haha woah thanks for the quick response yeah that solve the problem thanks a lot! and the floor area which i did not notice too xD